# How to feature detect W3C Clipboard API support in browsers?

Tags: javascript, browser, clipboard

The W3C Clipboard API support is limited in browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard

- Internet Explorer uses its own legacy solution
- Edge only supports writing and reading data with MIME type `text/plain`

For my purpose I would need to know if the following code would set data to the clipboard, or not (where `ev` is the clipboard event handler's event information object):

```
ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", "<b>some html</b>");
```

Since the object `ev` is only available after user interaction, the question is: Is there any other way to feature detect this without user interaction?